# How To Row Combine And Drop Columns In A List of Data Frames Based On Conditions

Tags: r, dataframe

Below is the example data which is list containing different data frames. I want to get one data frame out of it based on following two conditions.

First:

1. For each data frame in the list starting column 1 keep `rbind()`ing columns that have exact same column name as the previous one. The moment a different column name is encounter, drop that and all the columns till the last one.
2. For example: If column 1 is named `Banana`, then column 2 is named `Banana`, but column 3 is `Orange` and then again column 4 is `Banana`. Then column 1 and 2 will `rbind()` and column 3 and 4 will be dropped.
3. Another example: If column 1 is named `Banana` then column 2 is named `Orange`, but column 3 is named `Banana`, then only column 1 will survive as starting column 2 the column name is different and I don't care about column 3 name even though it's same as column 1.

Second:

1. After I run the list of data frame through above condition, then I want to combine all the data frames in the list to get one data frame which I think can be achieved using following code.
2. Here, `lst2` is output of first condition.

```
do.call(rowr::cbind.fill, c(lst2, list(fill = 0)))
```

Above code credit [@akrun](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3732271/akrun). Any suggestions will be helpful.

**Sample Data**

```
list(A = structure(list(`A-DIODE` = c(1.2, 0.4), `A-DIODE` = c(1.3, 
0.6)), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = "data.frame"), B = structure(list(
    `B-DIODE` = c(1.4, 0.8), `B-ACC1` = c(1.5, 1), `B-ACC2` = c(1.6, 
    1.2), `B-ANA0` = c(1.7, 1.4), `B-ANA1` = c(1.8, 1.6), `B-BRICKID` = c(1.9, 
    1.8), `B-CC0` = c(2L, 2L), `B-CC1` = c(2.1, 2.2), `B-DIGDN` = c(2.2, 
    2.4), `B-DIGDP` = c(2.3, 2.6), `B-DN1` = c(2.4, 2.8), `B-DN2` = c(2.5, 
    3), `B-DP1` = c(2.6, 3.2), `B-DP2` = c(2.7, 3.4), `B-SCL` = c(2.8, 
    3.6), `B-SDA` = c(2.9, 3.8), `B-USB0DN` = 3:4, `B-USB0DP` = c(3.1, 
    4.2), `B-USB1DN` = c(3.2, 4.4), `B-USB1DP` = c(3.3, 4.6), 
    `B-ACC1` = c(3.4, 4.8), `B-ACC2` = c(3.5, 5), `B-ANA0` = c(3.6, 
    5.2), `B-ANA1` = c(3.7, 5.4), `B-BRICKID` = c(3.8, 5.6), 
    `B-CC0` = c(3.9, 5.8), `B-CC1` = c(4L, 6L), `B-DIGDN` = c(4.1, 
    6.2), `B-DIGDP` = c(4.2, 6.4), `B-DN1` = c(4.3, 6.6), `B-DN2` = c(4.4, 
    6.8), `B-DP1` = c(4.5, 7), `B-DP2` = c(4.6, 7.2), `B-SCL` = c(4.7, 
    7.4), `B-SDA` = c(4.8, 7.6), `B-USB0DN` = c(4.9, 7.8), `B-USB0DP` = c(5L, 
    8L), `B-USB1DN` = c(5.1, 8.2), `B-USB1DP` = c(5.2, 8.4), 
    `B-NA` = c(5.3, 8.6), `B-ACC2PWRLKG_0v4` = c(5.4, 8.8), `B-ACC2PWRLKG_0v4` = c(5.5, 
    9), `B-P_IN_Leak` = c(5.6, 9.2)), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = "data.frame"))
```

---

**Update 1**

After [@ØysteinS](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5397495/%C3%98ystein-s) answer I realized that there should be a third condition too:

Third:

- If there is only a single column in one of the data frame in the list, then only that column be added to the parent data frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the job:

```r
data <- list(A = structure(list(`A-DIODE` = c(1.2, 0.4), `A-DIODE` = c(1.3, 
0.6)), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = "data.frame"), B = structure(list(
    `B-DIODE` = c(1.4, 0.8), `B-ACC1` = c(1.5, 1), `B-ACC2` = c(1.6, 
    1.2), `B-ANA0` = c(1.7, 1.4), `B-ANA1` = c(1.8, 1.6), `B-BRICKID` = c(1.9, 
    1.8), `B-CC0` = c(2L, 2L), `B-CC1` = c(2.1, 2.2), `B-DIGDN` = c(2.2, 
    2.4), `B-DIGDP` = c(2.3, 2.6), `B-DN1` = c(2.4, 2.8), `B-DN2` = c(2.5, 
    3), `B-DP1` = c(2.6, 3.2), `B-DP2` = c(2.7, 3.4), `B-SCL` = c(2.8, 
    3.6), `B-SDA` = c(2.9, 3.8), `B-USB0DN` = 3:4, `B-USB0DP` = c(3.1, 
    4.2), `B-USB1DN` = c(3.2, 4.4), `B-USB1DP` = c(3.3, 4.6), 
    `B-ACC1` = c(3.4, 4.8), `B-ACC2` = c(3.5, 5), `B-ANA0` = c(3.6, 
    5.2), `B-ANA1` = c(3.7, 5.4), `B-BRICKID` = c(3.8, 5.6), 
    `B-CC0` = c(3.9, 5.8), `B-CC1` = c(4L, 6L), `B-DIGDN` = c(4.1, 
    6.2), `B-DIGDP` = c(4.2, 6.4), `B-DN1` = c(4.3, 6.6), `B-DN2` = c(4.4, 
    6.8), `B-DP1` = c(4.5, 7), `B-DP2` = c(4.6, 7.2), `B-SCL` = c(4.7, 
    7.4), `B-SDA` = c(4.8, 7.6), `B-USB0DN` = c(4.9, 7.8), `B-USB0DP` = c(5L, 
    8L), `B-USB1DN` = c(5.1, 8.2), `B-USB1DP` = c(5.2, 8.4), 
    `B-NA` = c(5.3, 8.6), `B-ACC2PWRLKG_0v4` = c(5.4, 8.8), `B-ACC2PWRLKG_0v4` = c(5.5, 
    9), `B-P_IN_Leak` = c(5.6, 9.2)), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = "data.frame"))

# Use lapply to apply the same function to each data frame in the list.
combined_frames <- lapply(data, function(df){
  first_name <- names(df)[[1]]
  result <- df[, 1, drop = FALSE]
  # Keep adding if name is the same as the first
  if (ncol(df) != 1) {
   for(i in seq(2, length(names(df)), by = 1)){
     if(names(df)[[i]] == names(df)[[1]]){
       result <- rbind(result, df[, i, drop = FALSE])
     } else { 
       # Otherwise, break out of loop
       break
     }
   }
  }
  return(result)
})

# Yes, your suggested code seems to work as expected for the last task
do.call(rowr::cbind.fill, c(combined_frames, list(fill = 0)))
#>   A.DIODE B.DIODE
#> 1     1.2     1.4
#> 2     0.4     0.8
#> 3     1.3     0.0
#> 4     0.6     0.0
```

Comment: .@ØysteinS - Thanks. Will your code work if in the list a data frame has single column only? For the sample data I removed second column from the data frame `data$A` and it gives me error `Error in seq.default(2, length(names(df)), by = 1) : 
  wrong sign in 'by' argument `

Comment: .@ØysteinS - I think after `result <- df[ , 1, drop = FALSE]`, an `if else` is required that checks `ncol()` and executes the later part only if the `ncol()` is more than `1`. Do you agree?

Answer (score 1):

One easy option would be to loop through the `list`, get the run-length-id of the column names, extract only those equal to 1, `unlist`, convert to `data.frame` with the first column name and then with `cbind.fill` bind the `list` of data.frame`s together

```
library(data.table)
lst1 <- lapply(data, function(x) 
       setNames(data.frame(unlist(x[rleid(names(x)) == 1])), names(x)[1]))
do.call(rowr::cbind.fill, c(lst1, list(fill = 0)))
#    A.DIODE B.DIODE
#1     1.2     1.4
#2     0.4     0.8
#3     1.3     0.0
#4     0.6     0.0
```